# callback is not a funcion - JSON file read

Tags: node.js, express, node-oracledb

I did some research but all the responses that i get didn't resolved my problem.
Basically, i have the following code:

```
  public static load(lang: string, staReplace: boolean, callback?: (message: string, error?: string) => void) {
    if (!TranslateSingleton.languageFile) {
      TranslateSingleton.languageFile = new Map<string, Object>();
    }
    lang = lang.toLowerCase();
    if (!TranslateSingleton.languageFile.has(lang) || staReplace === true) {
      try {
        let strBody: string = fs.readFileSync(AppConfig.APP_SERVER_DIRETORIO + '/languages/language-' + lang + '.json', 'utf8')
        TranslateSingleton.languageFile.set(lang, JSON.parse(strBody));
        callback('OK', null);

      } catch (ex) {
        AppLog.error('IDIOMA NÃO ENCONTRADO ==>', AppConfig.APP_SERVER_DIRETORIO + '/languages/language-' + lang + '.json');
        callback(null, '## IDIOMA [' + lang + '] não disponível! ##');
      }
    }
  }
```

And when the 'load' function is called, i always get the response:

1) In the TS TranslateSingleton file:

```
TranslateSingleton.load(lang, false, null);
```

2) In another controller:

```
TranslateSingleton.load(resultToken.lang, true, (resultMessage, errorMessage) => {
              if (errorMessage) {
                resolve(super.trataErro(res, errorMessage));
              } else {
                resolve(super.trataRetorno(req, res, resultMessage));
              }
            });
```

And, then, my response:

```
[2020-06-10T11:47:06.257] [ERROR] default - [APPLOG] IDIOMA NÃO ENCONTRADO ==> [ './../languages/language-pt-br.json' ]
[2020-06-10T11:47:06.259] [ERROR] default - [APPLOG] Erro ao recuperar a chave: "AUDITORIA.REGISTRO_AUDITORIA",  [ TypeError: callback is not a function
      at Function.TranslateSingleton.load (C:\Users\emmanuel.oliveira\Documents\AgenciaWeb\aw-server\bin\util\translate.js:24:17)
      at TranslateSingleton.__ (C:\Users\emmanuel.oliveira\Documents\AgenciaWeb\aw-server\bin\util\translate.js:44:32)       
      at C:\Users\emmanuel.oliveira\Documents\AgenciaWeb\aw-server\bin\service\auditoria.service.js:423:62
      at C:\Users\emmanuel.oliveira\Documents\AgenciaWeb\aw-server\bin\service\base\base.service.js:374:29
      at custExecuteCb (C:\Users\emmanuel.oliveira\Documents\AgenciaWeb\aw-server\node_modules\oracledb\lib\connection.js:182:7) ]
```

Can someone give me a light in this?

Comment: How are you calling the `load` function? Your callback argument looks to be optional but within the function you have called callback without checking if the callback function is passed or not. If you have missing arguments then the callback argument will be `undefined` and you will be calling `undefined`, which throws an error since its not a function and cannot be invoked

Comment: I've updated my question with this points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by taking the following steps:

1) Changed the calling function

```
TranslateSingleton.load(lang, false, (a, b) => { });
```

2) Changed the path to root directory (only for dev instance)

PRD -> `./` 
DEV -> `./../`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are getting the error on this line of code:
`TranslateSingleton.load(lang, false, null);`

Here you have basically passed `null` as the argument for the `callback` parameter.

Inside the function body on line `callback('OK', null)`, this tries to invoke or call the function that you have passed as the callback argument. Since your argument is `null`, it cannot invoke since `null` is not a function, therefore it throws the error.

Comment: This is valid but this isn't resolved my problem. I think that my problem is probabilly at my baseService, where i have one oracle pool connection retrieving one callback (Even this making no sense).